# Spree Commerce bundler could not find compatible versions

Tags: ubuntu, spree

I'm trying to install spree commerce on my Ubuntu, I have Ruby on Rails already installed then I ran the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
gem install spree
spree install
```

after I type `bundle` I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    spree (~> 3.0.7) ruby depends on
      spree_core (= 3.0.7) ruby depends on
        sprockets-rails (~> 2.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.2.6) ruby depends on
      sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
bundle update
```

in your project root directory and later re-run spree install command.

This will be fixed in 3.0.8 release, sorry for the inconvenience!